# How to send "@" using AutoKey on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: script, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed [AutoKey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) on Ubuntu 14.04.

When writing AutoKey scripts, I've found that:

```
keyboard.send_key("@")
```

Sends "2".

How do a produce an "@" character in an AutoKey script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that

```
keyboard.send_keys('<shift>+@')
```

Will produce an "@". This is a feasible workaround for now, but I'd prefer to know why this is happening, or if there's some gross misunderstanding on my part.